# onKeyUp called when second button pressed

Tags: javascript

I'm making a custom input field which should support subscript. When the user presses the down arrow + a number, then the number should be in subscript. I appended a onKeyDown and onKeyUp event listener to a content editable paragraph. Unfortunately the onKeyUp gets called when the user presses the number, which results in adding the number twice (once in subscript and once normal). How can I solve this problem?

```
function keyDown(event) {
    var code = event.keyCode;
    if (code === 40) {
        option = 0;
    }
}

function keyUp(event) {
    var code = event.keyCode;
    if (code === 40 || code === 38) {
        option = -1;
    }
    console.log("release");
}
```

The onKeyPressed is not an option since this does not recognize the arrow keys in all browsers. Is there a native solution (without jQuery)?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to push the `keyCodes` into an *Array* on `keyDown` and `.splice()` it on `keyUp`.

All you have to do now is to check (probably against a pre-defined map) if the key states you desire are available in that *Array*.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your text field has focus, any numeral key you press will be added to it in addition to whatever your keyup or keydown listeners add to it. Maybe you should take away focus from the text field on keydown if the key you are pressing is the down key and add focus back again after the keyup event has fired.

```
/* Keep track of the down key. */
var down=false;
/* Get the input text field. */
var input=document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener("keydown",keyDown);
input.addEventListener("keyup",keyUp);

/* Give focus to input. I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, I haven't tested this code, but I know there's a way to give focus to elements and it sort of looks like this. */
input.focus();

function keyDown(event_){
    switch(event_.keyCode){
        case 40:
            /* Once again, not sure how to unfocus, but I know you can. */
            input.unfocus();
            down=true;
        break;
    }
}

function keyUp(event_){
    switch(event_.keyCode){
        case 40:
            /* Give focus back to input after the keyup event has fired. */
            input.focus();
            down=false;
        break;
    }
    if (down){
        input.value+=//The subscript version of whatever key you pressed.
    }
}
```

Once again, I would just like to say that this code hasn't been tested and I'm not sure if focus() and unfocus() are real methods, but you get the idea. You want to momentarily stop the text field from accepting input while the down key is pressed so you can add your own special value to it without updating it's contents with the default response and then give focus back to the text field once the down key is no longer in use.